# Let n be a square number. Using Python, how we can efficiently calculate natural numbers y up to a limit l such that n+y^2 is again a square number?

Tags: python, numeric

Using Python, I would like to implement a function that takes a natural number `n` as input and outputs a list of natural numbers `[y1, y2, y3, ...]` such that `n + y1*y1` and `n + y2*y2` and `n + y3*y3` and so forth is again a square.

What I tried so far is to obtain one `y`-value using the following function:

```
def find_square(n:int) -> tuple[int, int]:
    if n%2 == 1:
        y = (n-1)//2
        x = n+y*y
        return (y,x)
    return None
```

It works fine, eg. `find_square(13689)` gives me a correct solution `y=6844`. It would be great to have an algorithm that yields all possible `y`-values such as `y=44` or `y=156`.

Comment: Why are you returning `None` when `n` is even? There are even square numbers

Comment: There only solutions exist if the input value `n` is an odd integer. In our example `13689` is an odd integer. Mathematically, for an even `n` we will not find solutions, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4366995/for-a-given-integer-n0-can-we-efficiently-determine-whether-an-integer-y-e) on MSE.

Comment: What do you expect the type of the return value to be if a function could return all the possible y values?

Comment: A list of `y`-values would be fine. The more efficient (the less bruteforce), the better. Probably [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4367384/993738) is promising to avoid bruteforce.

Comment: So, what happened when you tried to return a `list`?

Comment: The trick, I am searching for, is to calculate this list as most efficient (avoiding bruteforce as drafted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4367384/993738)).

Comment: So, did you manage to implement a brute-force method?

Answer (score 6):

Simplest slow approach is of course for given N just to iterate all possible Y and check if `N + Y^2` is square.

But there is a much faster approach using integer [Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) technique:

Lets notice that to solve equation `N + Y^2 = X^2`, that is to find all integer pairs (X, Y) for given fixed integer N, we can rewrite this equation to `N = X^2 - Y^2 = (X + Y) * (X - Y)` which follows from famous school formula of difference of squares.

Now lets rename two factors as A, B i.e. `N = (X + Y) * (X - Y) = A * B`, which means that `X = (A + B) / 2` and `Y = (A - B) / 2`.

Notice that A and B should be of same odditiy, either both odd or both even, otherwise in last formulas above we can't have whole division by 2.

We will factorize N into all possible pairs of two factors (A, B) of same oddity. For fast factorization in code below I used simple to implement but yet quite fast algorithm [Pollard Rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm), also two extra algorithms were needed as a helper to Pollard Rho, one is [Fermat Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) (which allows fast checking if number is probably prime) and second is [Trial Division Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) (which helps Pollard Rho to factor out small factors, which could cause Pollard Rho to fail).

Pollard Rho for composite number has time complexity `O(N^(1/4))` which is very fast even for 64-bit numbers. Any faster factorization algorithm can be chosen if needed a bigger space to be searched. My fast algorithm time is dominated by speed of factorization, remaining part of algorithm is blazingly fast, just few iterations of loop with simple formulas.

If your N is a square itself (hence we know its root easily), then Pollard Rho can factor N even much faster, within `O(N^(1/8))` time. Even for 128-bit numbers it means very small time, 2^16 operations, and I hope you're solving your task for less than 128 bit numbers.

If you want to process a range of possible N values then fastest way to factorize them is to use techniques similar to [Sieve of Erathosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), using set of prime numbers, it allows to compute all factors for all N numbers within some range. Using Sieve of Erathosthenes for the case of range of Ns is much faster than factorizing each N with Pollard Rho.

After factoring N into pairs (A, B) we compute (X, Y) based on (A, B) by formulas above. And output resulting Y as a solution of fast algorithm.

Following code as an example is implemented in pure Python. Of course one can use [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to speed it up, Numba usually gives 30-200 times speedup, for Python it achieves same speed as optimized C++. But I thought that main thing here is to implement fast algorithm, Numba optimizations can be done easily afterwards.

I added time measurement into following code. Although it is pure Python still my fast algorithm achieves **8500x** times speedup compared to regular brute force approach for limit of 1 000 000.

You can change `limit` variable to tweak amount of searched space, or `num_tests` variable to tweak amount of different tests.

Following code implements both solutions - fast solution `find_fast()` described above plus very tiny brute force solution `find_slow()` which is very slow as it scans all possible candidates. This slow solution is only used to compare correctness in tests and compare speedup.

Code below uses nothing except few standard Python library modules, no external modules were used.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVdbT@s4EH7nV8zR6mzjEtKkCDiqKBI8nEd0tOKBqltFbuNQq4kTHBfag/jt7PjSXNqyYrWRaF1nbp7vmxlTbtWyEOc/SvnxkbAUUi6SuMqKV@@ejE4AH56XhVSQU7U0v82HFuVVXD2vqWTexonqRxaFgjFwoTytElTPUnlpVlCFYgROIQwuSCPN1FoKq9R3umPY@GbZuMvQ4nRmlmkhYYvmQVLxxOooTaTtmO7R1Rb6fRiSaThrhIy5gJYlE4m3JY0PF0pmd@pcpLRS@7ngiklVFFnlQ7oWC7NsDP2SRYLxZjSfJxRlR41QIFmyXjDPvaM@zEdA8eRzHwV9iFrxpBUaSSkqSvRvtnKz9/ZeJ4LpRKRVczqUmLIZCuEieGLKYz6EOutRY7PCI7DE0xJ4kLzyCHGYZlqtiWBipNEIqR0qumIx1V7rHAQlnne9UF5/WofhWXBetGOicVnBtzEMgWUVc8BFPrwgH7TRFS7tQWYtNG/RuU6lNy01jMqIeqUPMfHxF8r/5qWXIgY2KDJraHWHuvcwGMBtvUWrCgNGq339Fl/74OHfrQ93tYU2k27hGu66tFkUQnGxZvXmI7rxbvGQd0Q7G9YvJvbF2cELF4Um58SQU4fyaFbteB59mDTRTKqAJok3OSSrg3JSkRPDWCU5zeKEv8SOOMKHjOdcV@R9IZhL7x@wVKqsRoMBE8ErX/GSJZwGhXwa6F@Dh50ZXvFCNMxxJfi65BkDAX9CpMMPmywhpVxlDZvwBdzcjB0BaZbFiyVbrJgukZ8U@VBzK2mq@hyTYePGfWH462Mhd0o9QSQTuAHRBanr4UG24NLPXDK6qnfsSbRQ18gzNiDUxgzkSEBMYkI679G91IwOu2qHDrpJ2bMi0MXzibOHWcJ0UpG0T3Ass6Kd2V1eHR90NQhLhZRJ7L9xKUsdvyGGhvB8@EUO/Nzp85xmXG1jxSrVboKIVFLkTfjXGMvlaL@zCw2qh@RGSC98uMIeh1BG501L4Q3sNsouzCWOIusq0F96rqA1gbU1JPYb7SFFEI2oi4aLoCGZ2zCcMDkqiyyjMonlsqgL5ovp@WVVvw@vKqNOs6dCcrXM92em306UwQdROFanEVxfwxXpJvQgn64/8y7A5EDOdQYs21OYilkr3Uq2xuePlmZKsRi6ZamfDe58BkCji5YX20XGGtORO9JlSLq4bNHgplshXRoYNWONHNaXDsfbYO1v7HD5DuJARh/CXD6eFgnKnsFWU@RAzDSR8QFvPm33@3riuF6dx4Pm83mP@AS5IwRNyPF9oQdNQg76lI3m3/qUm0kGdbzQ9By14a9l4bS/GdK@ifde63K0u5l0bkbd69D/vwmZsXPktO5CVI/TsbsrpBWxcxQXJ8eSuhuU2My8buiW49gqeW5R2w1OQ8dhaPbEOjeNUIfltsyHClERpyHgd3istdWK3e7myWKNPZ3DoGW6D1EYhkRzGxdmxIKxhoQHHKW1ZBdVbNVYm2lPv4I3/u5DzwecGBhVD1dptq6WjpUNS@rFfbfMbdQmBUeE1Vw3MUxUoD@81n0@1JfW1v8QjUoIpx0dLEs1/y@mo51pdyVvVKKvmXZskSalMrJEkYiYXlsE9866S@nf4gENgz4TvKlwFIQX6TtejReYVqqzraL2XlUyZHcJbxZdPPoA@9HGi9jZpfFC3k24VQ/piCyIY0FzFsc6rl4c55SLOO5ZdC1TTz4@/gE)

```py
def find_slow(N):
    import math
    
    def is_square(x):
        root = int(math.sqrt(float(x)) + 0.5)
        return root * root == x, root
    
    l = []
    for y in range(N):
        if is_square(N + y ** 2)[0]:
            l.append(y)
    
    return l
    
def find_fast(N):
    import itertools, functools
    
    Prod = lambda it: functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, it, 1)
    
    fs = factor(N)
    mfs = {}
    for e in fs:
        mfs[e] = mfs.get(e, 0) + 1
    fs = sorted(mfs.items())
    del mfs
    
    Ys = set()
    for take_a in itertools.product(*[
        (range(v + 1) if k != 2 else range(1, v)) for k, v in fs]):
        A = Prod([p ** t for (p, _), t in zip(fs, take_a)])
        B = N // A
        assert A * B == N, (N, A, B, take_a)
        if A < B:
            continue
        X = (A + B) // 2
        Y = (A - B) // 2
        assert N + Y ** 2 == X ** 2, (N, A, B, X, Y)
        Ys.add(Y)
    
    return sorted(Ys)

def trial_div_factor(n, limit = None):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division
    fs = []
    while n & 1 == 0:
        fs.append(2)
        n >>= 1
    all_checked = False
    for d in range(3, (limit or n) + 1, 2):
        if d * d > n:
            all_checked = True
            break
        while True:
            q, r = divmod(n, d)
            if r != 0:
                break
            fs.append(d)
            n = q
    if n > 1 and all_checked:
        fs.append(n)
        n = 1
    return fs, n

def fermat_prp(n, trials = 32):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test
    import random
    if n <= 16:
        return n in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)
    for i in range(trials):
        if pow(random.randint(2, n - 2), n - 1, n) != 1:
            return False
    return True

def pollard_rho_factor(n):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm
    import math, random
    fs, n = trial_div_factor(n, 1 << 7)
    if n <= 1:
        return fs
    if fermat_prp(n):
        return sorted(fs + [n])
    for itry in range(8):
        failed = False
        x = random.randint(2, n - 2)
        for cycle in range(1, 1 << 60):
            y = x
            for i in range(1 << cycle):
                x = (x * x + 1) % n
                d = math.gcd(x - y, n)
                if d == 1:
                    continue
                if d == n:
                    failed = True
                    break
                return sorted(fs + pollard_rho_factor(d) + pollard_rho_factor(n // d))
            if failed:
                break
    assert False, f'Pollard Rho failed! n = {n}'
    
def factor(N):
    import functools
    Prod = lambda it: functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, it, 1)
    fs = pollard_rho_factor(N)
    assert N == Prod(fs), (N, fs)
    return sorted(fs)

def test():
    import random, time
    limit = 1 << 20
    num_tests = 20
    
    t0, t1 = 0, 0
    for i in range(num_tests):
        if (round(i / num_tests * 1000)) % 100 == 0 or i + 1 >= num_tests:
            print(f'test {i}, ', end = '', flush = True)
        
        N = random.randrange(limit)
        
        tb = time.time()
        r0 = find_slow(N)
        t0 += time.time() - tb
        
        tb = time.time()
        r1 = find_fast(N)
        t1 += time.time() - tb
        
        assert r0 == r1, (N, r0, r1, t0, t1)
        
    print(f'\nTime slow {t0:.05f} sec, fast {t1:.05f} sec, speedup {round(t0 / max(1e-6, t1))} times')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Output:

```
test 0, test 2, test 4, test 6, test 8, test 10, test 12, test 14, test 16, test 18, test 19,
Time slow 26.28198 sec, fast 0.00301 sec, speedup 8732 times
```

Comment: Now this is what I call an answer!

Comment: @Arty: This is really a very efficient solution - respect and a big thank you!

Comment: @EldarSultanow Thanks to you too! I'm going to implement C++ solution too. I can post it here or at GitHub if somebody will want it.

Answer (score 0):

For the easiest solution, you can try this:

```
import math
n=13689 #or we can ask user to input a square number.
for i in range(1,9999): 
    if math.sqrt(n+i**2).is_integer():
        print(i)
```

Comment: Result of `math.sqrt()` might be inprecise as it does floating arithmetics, hence `.is_integer()` may fail sometimes to detect integer value, and this will skip valuable candidate. We want precise algorithm, that's why there are two options 1) Starting from Python 3.8 there exists [math.isqrt()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt), which gives precise integer square root, you just need to check `if math.isqrt(n + i ** 2) ** 2 == n + i ** 2:`. 2) Second option is to do correct rounding `if round(math.sqrt(n + i ** 2)) ** 2 == n + i ** 2:`. Both solutions will work!

Comment: I don't think we will miss any value. Yes, return type of `math.sqrt()` is float but when it returns 2.0 for a square number 4, `is_integer()` will consider this an integer value as you can check here: [link](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html). But if you find out any counter example then we can think in some other way. Again, a counter example would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any floating point function is giving some errors, at least one bit of floating Mantissa always has error. So is SQRT, although it give good results but at least one-two bits in last digits are wrong. It means that many times SQRT accidentally gives not precisely an integer, especially if input X is large.I'm not saying that it is wrong to use SQRT,but that is wrong to check that final result if integer,it might be 1-2 bits different from integer unnoticably in very last bits that you don't see.I'm saying that correct ways of checking if it is an integer are different,as in my previous comment

Comment: As I said floating SQRT fails for big integers for example for X equal to `288230376151711839` we have `math.sqrt(X)` equal to `536870912.0` which it says that it is `.is_integer()` True, while `536870912 ** 2 == 288230376151711744` which is not equal original X. So it says that it is square while it is not (X is not square). [Here is code](https://cutt.ly/YOaLTZe) that prints all such bad numbers, that incorrectly work with your math.sqrt().is_integer(), while correctly works for math.isqrt()

Comment: Thanks for giving this counter example. Your approach is absolutey correct. Even **google calc** is behaving like `math.sqrt()`.

Comment: Anyway your solution may work correctly for smaller numbers. That counter-example is a big number. It overflows 53 bit mantissa of standard DOUBLE floating type. That's why it gives wrong result. So if input numbers have less bits than that counter-example then your code is alright. I'm just worying that `.is_integer()` may give wrong results sometimes even for small integers, because I don't know how it checks if it is integer. If it checks by `abs(num - round(num)) < small_epsilon` then it is alright, but if it checks `abs(num - round(num)) == 0` then it is wrong and give wrong results somet